# Using "hover" to a "menu" to show an image inside a "div"

Tags: html, css, image, menu, hover

I need to use the mouse to hover a menu to make an image appear inside a DIV below.

```css
ul li a:hover {
  background: #43FD49;
}

div#firefox {
  align: center;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  background-image: url(img1.jpg);
  display: none;
}

ul li a#imgfirefox:hover+div#firefox {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">algo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a id="imgfirefox" href="#">Firefox</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Chrome</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Opera</a></li>
</ul>

<div>
  <div id="firefox"></div>
</div>
```

I expect to hover over the "Firefox" and a image of the Firefox browser appear below, inside the div. Now when you hover over "Firefox" it does nothing.

Comment: would you be ok with a JavaScript approach?

Comment: You can't do it with CSS alone unless you change your HTML structure

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<li><a id="imgfirefox" href="#">Firefox</a><img src="ff.jpg"></li>
```

And use CSS as,

```
div#firefox img{display:none}

div#firefox img:hover{display:block}
```

rather than using a background image.

**PS: Also you should use `background-image: url("img1.jpg");`, with quotes**

Answer (score 0):

Consider a JavaScript approach or do as follows:

```
#firefox:hover{
    background-image: url('img1.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the structure of the HTML

```css
ul li a:hover {
  background: #43FD49;
}

#firefox {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
}

#imgfirefox:hover ~ #firefox {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">algo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li id="imgfirefox" ><a href="#">Firefox</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Chrome</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Opera</a></li>
  
  <div id="firefox"></div>
</ul>
```